# Simple XML Element fail to parse a <link type=""> string from an .atom file

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, atom-feed

I've this piece of code taken by a .atom document wrapped with file_get_contents:

```
<entry>
    <link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="..."/>
</entry>
```

My goal is to extract the first URL into the href attribute in the entry tag, i tried to parse with:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($XML_file);
$link = $xml->entry[0]->link;
print $link;
```

But shell does not give me any output.

Comment: What does the full atom doc look like? Is it valid XML?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, it's completely valid. You can see the entire file in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try? As your link element looks empty.

```
<entry>
    <link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="...">Something</link>
</entry>
```

And than your php?

That is my point, t is exactly what you try to echo.
to get attributes

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

```
$text = '<entry><link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="..." /></entry>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($text);
$linkAttributes = $xml->link->attributes();
foreach ($linkAttributes as $key => $value)  {
    echo $key . '::' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

outputs:

```
type::text/html
rel::alternate
href::...
```

Comment: there's no "Something". Syntax is : `<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href=""/>. You can see the entire code in the edit.

Comment: I cannot understand how to manipulate the attributes as is described in the PHP manual example.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was easier than i thought ;)

Comment: Note that you can also access attribute values by name like you would with an array. For example,  `echo $xml->entry->link['href'];`

Answer (score 0):

When you load an xml document, the document *is* the root element (in this case `<entry>`). Therefore, you want:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($XML_file);
$link = $xml->link;
print $link;
```

Comment: Shell still does not give me anything.